# How we disable datepicker except startdate and end date

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to disable datepicker except date range like start date and end date dynamically

```
$.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: url,
        success: function (data) 
            $('#datetimepicker').datepicker({
                startDate: data.StartDate,
                endDate: data.EndDate
            });
            $('#datetimepicker').val(data.StartDate);  
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you give us HTML template ?

Comment: Which datepicker you use? Can you provide link?

Comment: Not sure what you mean disable except daterange? Is it disabled or not? do you mean you want to disable "dates" in datepicker except the start and end date and maybe all inbetween? like allow user to pick a date between available date range?

Comment: I am using jquery date picker I have months in the database with date range like start date and end date. when I select any month from dropdown then I want to enable date range of a selected month   with ajax                                                 
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: url,
        success: function (data) 
            $('#datetimepicker').datepicker({
                startDate: data.StartDate,
                endDate: data.EndDate
            });
            $('#datetimepicker').val(data.StartDate);  
        }
    });